# DUDA VUE, error para escuchar evento desde un componente a la instancia principal(single file components)

Tags: vue.js

El problema es cuando desde un componente listaClientes uso un emit para que lo escuche la instancia principal al agregar un cliente, no logro ver el error. solo uso un this.$emit en el componente y un this.$on en la app.

asi esta listaClientes.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>

     <h1>lista de clientes</h1>

     <div v-if="listaclientes">

        <input type="text" v-model="cliente_agregar">
        <input type="button" value="Agregar cliente" @click="agregarCliente">
        <ul>

        <li v-for ="cliente in listaclientes">
          {{ cliente.nombre  }} -
          <button @click="eliminarcliente(cliente.nombre)">Eliminar</button>
          <button @click="seleccionar(cliente.nombre)">Mostrar Receta</button>
        </li>
  
         </ul>
     </div>
     <span v-else>No hay clientes agregados </span>
    
     <hr>
           
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

  props: ['listaclientes'],

  methods : {

    agregarCliente(){
     
      alert('esto en el metodo agregar clientes');
      
        this.$emit('agregar',  this.cliente_agregar );
   
    },

    seleccionar(nombre){

       this.$emit('seleccionado', nombre );
    
      },

    },
  
  data () {
    return {

      buscar : '', 
      clientes : this.listaclientes,
      cliente_agregar : null,

    }
  },

}
    </script>
```

y este es App.vue

```js
<template>

  <div id="app" >

    <listaClientes :listaclientes="clientes">
    </listaClientes>

    <h2 ></h2>

    <div v-if="farmacos">
       <farmacos :nombre="farmaco.nombre" :precio="farmaco.precio" v-for="(farmaco,key,value) in farmacos" ></farmacos>
    </div>
    <span v-else>No hay farmacos agregados</span>
           
  </div>
</template>

<script>

    import listaClientes from './components/listaClientes.vue';
  
    import farmacos from './components/farmacos.vue';
    import receta from './components/receta.vue';

export default {

  name : 'app',

  components: { listaClientes , farmacos},

  data () {
    return {

      clientes : [

        {nombre: 'lucas', farmacos: [
          {nombre:'aspirina',precio:500},
          ]
        },
         
      ],

      farmacos : [
        {nombre:'antibioticos', precio:5000 }
      ],

      recetas  : null,

      cliente_sel : null,

    }
  },

  created : function() {
    this.$on('seleccionado', (nombre) => {
       
       this.cliente_sel=nombre; 
    });

    this.$on('agregar', (cliente_agregar) => {
      
       this.clientes.push(
        {nombre: cliente_agregar , farmacos: null },
        ); 
    });
    
  },
  
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Comment: al final el problema era bastante claro. solo se puede hacer eso usando un eventBus, sino se debe poner el evento en el componente.

Comment: usar this.$emit('evento'), y luego en el componente correspondiente el atributo @evento